# apt-get: No such file or directory

Tags: apt

i don't know why i suddenly can't do something with apt-get such as `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install blabla`

this is output for `uname -a` :

```
Linux adelleodel-X450CC 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

file apt-get :

```
apt-get: ERROR: cannot open `apt-get' (No such file or directory)
```

cat /etc/lsb-release:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

ls -l /usr/bin/apt-get :

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/apt-get: No such file or directory
```

dpkg -l apt :

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-================================================================
rc  apt                           1.0.1ubuntu2.11     amd64               commandline package manager
```

echo $PATH :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

i've searched before about this and some people said that i have to download something and dpkg it. how to do it then? can someone give the link and step by step how to do it?
Thanks a lot!!!!

-----editted-----
actually, i did `sudo apt-get remove libusb-0.1-4:amd64` and some package autoremove with it i think..
i did that because i thought it wasn't belong with my program,.. because i have **libusb-1.0-0:amd64**, **libusb-1.0-0-dev:amd64**, and **libusb-1.0-doc**

i've tried `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb`

the result is :

```
--2016-02-08 19:56:19--  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb
Resolving security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.13, 91.189.92.200, 91.189.92.201, ...
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 952468 (930K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb’

100%[======================================>] 952.468      245KB/s   in 3,8s   

2016-02-08 19:56:29 (245 KB/s) - ‘apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb’ saved [952468/952468]
```

after that, `sudo dpkg -i apt_apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb`

the result is :

```
dpkg: error processing archive apt_apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt_apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb
adelleodel@adelleodel-X450CC:~$ sudo dpkg -i apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 230272 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.0.1ubuntu2.11) over (0.8.10.3+squeeze1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6 on system is 4.4.5-8.
 apt depends on gnupg; however:
  Package gnupg is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

Comment: How did you remove `apt-get`? Do not tell that "you did not do anything".

Comment: The `dpkg -l` lines show that you have removed the `apt` package, and only a few configuration files remain. Bad Puppy! No Cookie!

Comment: er.... actually i did sudo apt-get remove libusb-0.1-4:amd64.

Comment: what to do then? T^T heeelp heeelp. i did remove some package that i think not belong with my program in ROS.

Comment: Probably you meant `file $(which apt-get)`.  `file apt-get` wouldn't tell you anything unless your working directory was where you had it installed (usually `/usr/bin`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to download now the apt .deb package on your system from 
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/

Open a terminal(Ctrl-Alt-t) type:

32 Bit:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_v_x_x_x_i386.deb
```

Or

64 Bit:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_v_x_x_x_amd64.deb
```

Install it by typing:

```
sudo dpkg -i  apt_apt_v_x_x_x_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i  apt_apt_v_x_x_x_amd64.deb
```

Or

Try to install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: how do i know which one is my version?

Comment: i've tried it with 1.0.1ubuntu2.11, but after i installed it, the output is like my update question.

Comment: Recomended to use latest version. as I am using  "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS" and get output for supported version. by typing  _apt list apt_ Listing... Done  _apt/trusty-updates 1.0.1ubuntu2.11 i386 [upgradable from: 1.0.1ubuntu2.6]_ so you can decide which version you have to use. select and install.

Comment: wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/trusty-updates_1.0.1ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb
 like this? i got error from it..